# ラズベリーパイで動作する自作OSを作るには何を勉強すべきなのか知りたい。

Tags: raspberry-pi

###### 質問内容

以下の条件で操作するOSを作成したいのですがまずはどんな知識が必要なのでしょうか？
沢山検索しましたが以下の事がわからないので知りたいです。

###### 知りたい事

linuxベースとはそもそもなにか？
コーディング方法？
使う言語アセンブラ？C言語？
とりあえず画面にHello worldを表示させるまでよ手順

###### 調べたこと

PCが起動するまでの仕組みを調べました。
bios,ブートローダ、カーネルについて調べました
OSが起動するまでの順序等を調べました。

###### 条件

Raspberry Pi 4 model B で動作するlinux OS

###### 参考サイト

A: https://kozos.jp/kozos/
B: http://yuma.ohgami.jp/x86_64-Jisaku-OS/
起動の仕組み: https://www.pmi-sfbac.org/linux-kernel/
linux: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
linux カーネル: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB
linux カーネルダウンロード: https://www.kernel.org/
PC起動: https://behind-memoirs.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/11/14/021856

Comment: raspberry piというより、PCを調べているように見えます。
簡単なのから調べるつもりなら、Pi 4よりはPi picoのようなマイコンの方がいいように思います。手頃なサイズのOpenSourceなOSもいくつかあるし。
逆に高機能なもので動かしたいなら始めからVM環境の豊富なPCの方がいいような気がします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですがとりあえずコーティングしみたいのですがそれを行うにはどういった手順を踏むのでしょうか？

Comment: それとは何でしょう？
具体的な質問になったら別途質問を上げたら他の人が答えてくれるかもしれません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> linuxベース

[Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) な OSには各種あり (リンク内の図を参照のこと),
[BSDの子孫](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90%E5%AD%AB) や [System V](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V)系がある中, どちらでもない OSとして Linuxがあります。
先の 各 familyにはいくつもの OSが存在してるけど, Linuxは単独

Linuxは 正しくは(OS全体ではなく) カーネルを指し, ディストリビューションとは(カーネル以外の)各種ソフトなど組み込んだもの
例えば Debian系ディストリビューションと Red Hat系ディストリビューションでは, パッケージ管理ツールなど含め 各種の違いがあります

(伝わるかわからないが) メーカー製パソコン / 自作パソコン の違いで, (ディストリビューションの違いは)自作パソコンの組み立て方(パーツの選択)の違い, という感じでしょうか？

参考: [Linuxディストリビューション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)

---

> コーディング方法？
> 使う言語アセンブラ？C言語？

カーネルに機能を組み込むには, C言語 もしくは Rust言語 で行うことになります

そうではなく (自作パソコンで言うところの) 組み立てたいと言うことなら, まずは PCで行ってみるのがよいでしょう

- [Linux From Scratch](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)

  - [LFSブック日本語版 (lfsbookja)](http://lfsbookja.osdn.jp/)
- [Gentoo Linux](https://www.gentoo.org/)

後者は (目的が異なり) 組み立てではないが, ほぼ全てビルドするので雰囲気は伝わりやすいかも (学習できるかどうかは別として)

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問ですがOSとはカーネルを触るプログラムなのでしょうか？

Comment: 「OSとは」だと範囲が広すぎです。一応「[オペレーティングシステム](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/オペレーティングシステム)」…目的によって守備範囲もこなるので。[LFSに記されてるソフト](http://lfsbookja.osdn.jp/11.2-ja/) ビルドしてみるとなにか掴めるかも (ただし記されてるものすべてビルドしても GUI などはオプション … (GUI望むならば) さらに用意していかないとデスクトップ OSはできない)